# which file is responsible for searching wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to edit the search logic in WordPress, after searching if he did not find anything, open one page, and if he found something, then another page. The problem is that I cannot find the file that describes the search functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the technical know how, just google 'WordPress search plugins' , these will do the same job without coding.